# temporary styling of placeholder text in input field on focus

Tags: css

Can the placeholder text of a input field be altered based on when it's active?

The placeholder get's active via jQuery.

So that when it's active the input field get's visually different.

Comment: Just a note: when you start typing, the placeholder disappears *already*.

Comment: Your question doesn't entirely make sense to me. Can you show us an example of how you would like it to look?

Comment: See https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/ for tips on styling placeholders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure can!

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #000;
}
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #ff0000;
}
input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #000;
}
input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #ff0000;
}
input::-moz-input-placeholder {
    color: #000;
}
input:focus::-moz-input-placeholder {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: Changed to include FF/IE.